# pygtk statusBar will not update from signal handler

Tags: pygtk, python-2.7

So I have been pulling my hair out all day at this, and I am out of patience.

Basically I have a pygtk program that is built from glade. At the bottom of the main window, there is a status bar that I use to display usage errors, and status messages about the connected hardware and they use the functions below. So all of the calls to displayError come from within my object based on user interaction, and they all seem to work. In testing I tried making calls to displayCurrent and it works as well. The problem comes when the hardware process tries to use displayCurrent. The way the system works is that one of the members of my main window class is an interface object to the hardware. This has a separate process, using multiprocessing.Process, which sends a signal every time it gets data with the data being the message to output. Does anyone have any ideas? I'll be happy to explain anything in more depth if needed, it's just a LOT of code to post to get all the details.

```
def displayCurrent(self, message):
    print message
    if self.lastMess:
        self.statusBar.remove(self.normalID, self.lastMess)
    self.lastMess = self.statusBar.push(self.normalID, message)

def displayError(self, message, timeout = 5):
    """
    Function that takes an error message and raises it to the user via the statusbar
    timeout seconds later. 
    """
    print message
    mess = self.statusBar.push(self.urgentID, message)
    # clear statusbar
    gobject.timeout_add_seconds(timeout, self.clearStatus, self.urgentID, mess)

def clearStatus(self, cID, mID):
    #time.sleep(timeout)
    self.statusBar.remove(cID, mID)
    #print self.statusBar.remove_all(self.urgentID)
    print 'popped'
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Post the whole code.

In general, this won't work if you are in a separate process. GTK (and everything else) has been forked. You need to use some form of interprocess communication. Multiprocessing module handles it for you. There are also hacks you can do in GTK such as using a window title (like Vim) or perhaps a plug and socket to communicate; don't be tempted by these.